# USDX Sub-circuit Question

Tags: circuit-design

Can someone please explain what the sub-circuit that I have highlighted does?

[image]

Image Credit: https://github.com/threeme3/usdx/blob/master/usdx.png

Comment: It's a low pass filter as per the block diagram you ought to have inspected: https://github.com/threeme3/usdx/blob/master/block.png